# Appropriate model when target value equals one of the features

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear

Consider a simplified example where we are trying to predict some value `val` which happens to be equal to one of the `num_*` features. The task of the model is to select which of these `num_*` features to focus on, depending on the values of other features.

| color | size | shape | num_1 | num_2 | num_3 | num_4 | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blue | large | rectangle | 0.3 | 0.6 | 0.0 | NaN | 0.6 |
| blue | large | rectangle | 0.7 | 0.2 | -0.3 | 0.1 | 0.2 |
| red | small | square | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.3 | NaN | 0.3 |
| red | small | square | -0.4 | 0.5 | -0.5 | -0.5 | -0.5 |
| green | medium | round | -0.2 | 0.5 | 0.0 | 0.1 | -0.2 |
| blue | medium | oval | 0.7 | -0.3 | -0.1 | 0.5 | -0.5 |

What the model would learn in this toy example, is that when we have a `blue, large, rectangle` object, then `val` would mostly be equal to `num_2`, while when having a `red, small, square` object, then `val` would mostly follow `num_3`. Note that this is a toy example, an in reality, there are many categorical features (several dozens) with a cardinality varying between 10 and 500. The number of `num_*` columns is between 10 and 15.

We tried approaching this problem with boosted trees (using XGBoost) but it doesn't seem to generalise well, as trees are unable to learn a direct linear relationship as such (only mimic it with a high enough number of splits). Boosted linear models (such as XGBoost with `gblinear` base model) do not seem to work a lot better.

What would be an appropriate choice of ML model for this kind of task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a classification problem. Add a column to your data indicating which of the `num_*` features matches the target for each row, and train a classifier to predict that.